# Creating multiple imp (mice) objects using for loop

Tags: r, r-mice

I have this data from questionnaires. To explore the data and to impute the NA's I have to use seperate data sets. Here is some dummy code where you see my multiple df's (for each age category a seperate df) :

```
library(mice)
set.seed(4711)
sex <- rbinom(20, 1, 0.5)
age_categories <- c("00_08", "09_10", "11_12", "13_14", "15plus")
age_cat <- sample(age_categories, 20, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(c(1:5, NA),20,rep=TRUE)))
df <- cbind(age_cat, sex, df)
for (i in age_categories){ assign(paste0("to_imp_", i), df[df$age_cat == i,-1])}
```

What I want with these df's is to create an 'imp' object for every df, like:

```
imp_00_08 <- mice(to_imp_00_08, printFlag = FALSE)
imp_09_10 <- mice(to_imp_09_10, printFlag = FALSE)
```

and so on.

But of course I want this in a smarter way with less programming. I have tried:

```
for (p in age_categories){ assign(paste0("imp_", p), mice(paste0("to_imp_", p)))}
```

but this throws an error of course, because the second part `mice(paste0("to_imp_", p))` is not telling mice to do something with an R object, but with a text.

I also tried it with a list of all objects, but that too I can't seem to get it working. Hope one of you really smart people can help me out.

Comment: You need to wrap the text from `paste0("to_imp_", p)` in `get` like this: `for (p in age_categories){ assign(paste0("imp_", p), mice(get(paste0("to_imp_", p))))}`

Comment: Typical beginners failure, didn't knew (or remembered?) the 'get' command. Thank you very, very, much, Jaap!

Comment: Another way to get separate dataframes: `list2env(split(df[,-1], paste0('to_imp_',df$age_cat)), envir = .GlobalEnv)`